# Inject Dependency in View Location Expander

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have implemented a Custom ViewLocationExpander in a vnext project. I want to read a app setting value from the appsettings.json file in the ViewLocationExpander and hence the IOptions<> has been injected into the custom ViewLocationExpander 's constructor. However, while adding the custom ViewLocationExpander to the RazorViewEngine options an object of the ViewLocationExpander is required, which cannot be created due to the dependency.

Below is the code

```
public MyViewLocationExpander(IOptions<MyAppSettings> MyAppSettings) 
{
  var appSettings = MyAppSettings.Value;
  client = appSettings.Client // client is a private field and is used in ExpandViewLocations function
}
```

MyAppSettings.cs is as below:

```
public class MyAppSettings
{
  public string Client { get; set; }
}
```

In Startup.cs ConfigureServices method

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(config =>
{
  //config.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new MyViewLocationExpander());
  // MyViewLocationExpander cannot be created as it has a dependency on IOptions<MyAppSettings>
});
```

Any help on how to add the custom ViewLocationExpander to the RazorViewEngineOptions would be great.

Comment: one way, maybe not pretty, is to make the constructor of your expander take an IServiceCollection and then just pass in "services" which would allow you to retrieve the options

Comment: I have couple of ways to resolve the issue: 1. I passed in the "Configuration" to the constructor and used the Configuration["appSettingKey"]. 2. I removed the constructor from the ViewLocationExpander and accessed context.ActionContext.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IOptions<MyAppSettings>)) but these seems to me as anti-patterns (not pretty) hence maybe some one can give a better solution.

Comment: there is a blog post here that might give you an idea, using saaskit he gets a tenant instance inside a view expander without much ugly business http://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-core-themes-and-multi-tenancy

Comment: I finally did it using the option 2 mentioned in my comment above. Same method has been used in the link to the blog above.

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve services from the container is to resolve them in `ExpandViewsMethod`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
{
    var service = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IService>();
}
```